# Why does my Threadpool get stuck unless a MessageBox is placed before WaitHandle?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, command-line, threadpool

The Threadpool I have created starts but does not complete if started from complete when open the .exe file or execute it from the command line, it will only fully run if the Debugger is run.

I have written WinForms program to create a Threadpool with two threads and wait until the threads complete to wrap up the program.

I have written it so that I can start the .exe from the command line and take in arguments, but the issue I'm having is that the threads start, but for some reason gets stuck before the WaitHandle.WaitAll() unless it is run with the Debugger. The one thing I have noticed is that when I place a MessageBox before the WaitHandle, it will finish, but I need the program to run in the background without any MessageBox.

```
eventArray = new AutoResetEvent[2];
eventArray[0] = new AutoResetEvent(false);
eventArray[1] = new AutoResetEvent(false);

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(o =>
{
errors000 = Process000Or001(table, "000", eventArray[0], logFile835, batchID);
}), eventArray[0]);


ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(o =>
{
errors001 = Process835Or837(table, "001", eventArray[1], logFile837, batchID);
}), eventArray[1]);

//MessageBox.Show("");

WaitHandle.WaitAll(eventArray);

//program wraps up
```

I am not getting any error Messages, I have created logs for both threads, and I see it writes the first line in the log when I execute from command line, but it only writes that one when I expect 10-12 more lines. I even see the program running in Task Manager, but it just seems to be stuck.

Comment: Sounds like your signaling evets are just not set so that `WaitAll` just waits.

Comment: I have a `.Set()` at the end of the method before the return value, so it should be getting set. Again it does complete when run with the debugger.

Comment: Created a dummy app where I replaced yout `errors = ....` with just `eventArray[0].Set()` (and the same for the other event in the other callback). And it works correctly in both Debug and Release mode. Can you confirm?

Comment: That works but I need that line? Its the main method of the program that I'm writing...

Comment: Either way I found away around by automatically opening and closing a message box.